# Inserting SQL Data From Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress, sql-insert

I created a custom table in my WP database to collect some basic info, but I can't seem to get this function to insert. The table has the following columns, id, name, city, state, and product. The id is set as my primary key and is set to auto increment.

I'm not going to give the entire function, just the relevant insert portion. All the variables have been defined and the function itself does get called. Prior to adding the sql portion I called the function on a test page and had everything printed out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to use the wordpress sql class.

```
$table = 'my_test_table';
    $data = array('name' => $name, 'city' => $city, 'state' => $state, 'product' => $product_name);  

    $wpdb->insert($table, $data);
```

Comment: Do you have `global $wpdb;` in your function ?

Comment: You should go through the codex of Wordpress on how you should handle db things.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: That's what I was missing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Kaloyan pointed out I was missing:

```
global $wpdb;
```

Thanks.